# PDFKit: save UTF8 special characters

Tags: javascript, utf-8, pdfkit

is it possible to save characters such as "ěščřžýáé" in text to PDF using PDFkit?

Their browser demo is here:
http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html

Note: I use only js libraries, no node.js etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. You only need to use font that supports those characters.